# Работа с архивами ARJ в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго дня!

Возникла необходимость работы (в частности, упаковка) с архивами в формате [ARJ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/arj/) (требование контрагента — госструктура, ага), так вот, если с распаковкой архива всё относительно просто (есть 7z и, [например](https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor), wrapper'ы для него), то с запаковкой всё несколько сложнее.

**Посему вопрос - есть ли какие-либо пакеты (библиотеки, классы и т.д.) где бы была поддержана работа (запаковка и распаковка) с ARJ напрямую в .NET?**

Может быть есть какие-то еще способы выполнить создание ARJ-архива, помимо вызова консольного ARJ.EXE?

**UPD.** [SevenZipSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipSharp/) не предлагать: при всем уважении к этой библиотеке, это обертка над семейством библиотек 7z.dll, а 7z не может запаковывать в ARJ, хотя с распаковкой проблем нет.

Comment: Есть на с++ библиотеки, а вот переписал ли их кто на c# не знаю, там хороший кусок.

Comment: Может вот эта ссылка поможет http://stackoverflow.com/a/3238468/5727271

Comment: Упаковки - нет. Распаковки в принципе тоже. Пишите обертку над `arj32.exe` или что там нынче.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо, для распаковки есть разные варианты, например http://stackoverflow.com/a/36890576/6935496 а вот с запаковкой всё печальнее. Переводить архиватор с C в C# крайне не хотелось бы (слишком долго и не оправданно получится).

Comment: @Monk, видимо, так и придется поступить, к сожалению.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант - скачайте паковщик для линукса, он хорошо написан, или другие исходники arj, - соберите на с++ библиотеку, с "хорошими" функциями, и прилинкуйте её к с# через Interprop

Comment: Возможно, самым простым вариантом будет таки работа с консольным arj.exe. По идее, вам придётся просто [спрятать консоль](http://stackoverflow.com/a/836436/276994).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, похоже на то. Отдельная благодарность за ссылочку на то, как спрятать консоль, в которой работает "чужое" приложение.

Comment: @BlackWitcher: Пожалуйста! Я помню, что мне приходилось тоже заморачиваться с убиранием консоли.

Comment: В nuget есть библиотека [SevenZipSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipSharp/). Поддерживает как извлечение, так и сжатие во множество форматов, в числе которых и arj. Пробуйте.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, я видел эту либу и ее форк на гит-хабе, но не смог найти в описании точный список поддерживаемых форматов для распаковки и паковки, потому пока не стал качать и разбираться с ней. Но если вы так ответили, что ARJ поддержан, то посмотрю на нее более внимательно. Спасибо!

Comment: А вот история создания этой библиотеки, если интересно: https://habrahabr.ru/post/103521/

Comment: Тут только пытать портировать вот это [ссылка](https://github.com/joncampbell123/arj), или переходить на 7zip всей госструктурой.

Comment: Вот [тут](http://www.fileformat.info/format/arj/corion.htm) есть полное описание формата arj, можно самому написать нужный функционал.